# TyphoonStoryboard problems

Tags: ios, typhoon

i'm trying to instantiateInitial viewControllers manually and stuck with next thing.

This is working:

```
-(TyphoonStoryboard *)storyboard {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:@"Diary"];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }];

        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
}];
}

-(LADiaryMainViewController *)mainViewController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:[self storyboard] selector:@selector(instantiateInitialViewController)];
}
```

and this one is not working:

```
-(TyphoonStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:name];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }];
    }];
}

-(LADiaryMainViewController *)mainViewController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:[self storyboardWithName:@"Diary"] selector:@selector(instantiateInitialViewController)];
}
```

Second way is crashes with: `[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.. Sorry, `factory definition` with runtime argument was not supported in Typhoon. But.. We've added that feature for you!

Check Typhoon `3.1.9` version, your code should work fine now.